# Функция, которая парсит и обрезает строку с конца до первого найденого пробела

Tags: javascript

Строка подаётся в виде:

```
var str1 = "75 80 85";
var str2 = "75.0 80.5 91. 95.3";
var str3 = "150";
```

Есть ли какие-то методы в JS которые могут пропарсить строку с конца, до первого пробела (если таковой имеется)? Чтобы получить с первой строки - *85*, со второй - *95.3*, а с третьей *150*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Такого метода нет. Но то что вы хотите, можно сделать кучей разных способов. Например, так

```
var last = str1.split(' ').pop()
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
'use scrict';
var string = '150',
    arrayString = string.split(' ');
arrayString.reverse();
console.log(arrayString[0]);
string = '75.0 80.5 91. 95.3';
arrayString = string.split(' ');
arrayString.reverse();
console.log(arrayString[0]);
```